# Post not displaying in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am doing theme integration in wordpress.I created home.php (template page) and select from backend(for front end page).
Now i want to show posts on front page.I put following code for display post in front page.But code is not working.Where i am wrong ?
Here is my code

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
  the_content(); 
endwhile; 
endif; 
?>
```

Comment: Can you please paste the code? I think you forgot to add the code.

Comment: @Tejas Shah :

here is my code

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
             
 the_content(); 
        
   endwhile; endif; ?>

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code -

```
<?php
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'));
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>                          

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php esc_html(the_title()); ?></a>       

        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <?php
     endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```